# MySQL trigger: undefined variable 'tableName'

Tags: mysql, triggers, ddl

I am unable to see what is wrong with this trigger definition...I don't know if the select query is faulty or somewhere else.

The idea is when a row is inserted in tableA, the trigger performs a `SELECT` on tableB to retrieve some data and **insert** or **update** tableC.

Error:

`SQL Error [1327] [42000]: Undeclared variable: aTable`

Trigger DDL:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT
ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE varA integer;
DECLARE varB integer;

IF NEW.`Type` = 'comment' THEN
        
    SELECT
        myOtherTable.Id INTO varA
        ,aTable.Id INTO varB
    FROM myOtherTable <----- maybe here
    JOIN aTable ON aTable.id = myOtherTable.aTableId
    WHERE myOtherTable.Id = NEW.Id;

    Insert INTO myThirdTable VALUES 
        (NEW.Id, NEW.time, varA)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...;
END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

UPDATE 03/12/2020
It seems that adding a second `INTO varB` leads to the error that the `aTable` variable is undeclared.

Comment: Published code does not produce published error.

Comment: @p.Salmon is it clearer? I tried to built a DDL as close as the actual use case

Comment: That’s not the correct syntax for select into please read manual

Comment: Thank you https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Answer (score 1):

Test single-statement form:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT
ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO myThirdTable (id, `time`, a)
SELECT NEW.Id, NEW.time, myOtherTable.Id
FROM myOtherTable
WHERE myOtherTable.Id = NEW.Id
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...;
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works and not the SELECT query outside of the insert?

Comment: @Kaymaz I cannot. As P.Salmon tells (correctly!) your code cannot produce shown message. So something is lost/altered between the code which produces shown error and posted code.

Comment: @Akine See update. a second INTO seems to be the problem.